# Bounds and Frame size in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, bounds

I push a view controller (`mainVC`) and add some subviews to it. Most of these views are built on-demand, as the user takes some action.

When I build each view, I refer to `mainVC.view.bounds` to size the view. The ones that are built on demand size just fine, but the first one (which I add in `viewDidLoad`) does not seem to account for either the hidden navigation bar or the unhidden toolbar - I'm not sure which.

Other questions seem to assure me that viewDidLoad is the correct place to refer to the bounds and to add these subviews. Am I misinformed?  Logging yields the following:

In `viewDidLoad` the bounds height is 548.

In `viewWillAppear` the bounds height is 460 (-44 x 2). In `viewWillAppear` I hide the navigation bar, but the height is the same before and after.

At all later times, the bounds height is 504 (-44 x 1).

Why is the bounds height not updated by the time I attempt to read it in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I assume that when the nib is first loaded, the view is whatever size you set it. When its ends up as a subview in the window, the system sizes it appropriate for where its located (I assume). Note there is no "hard" size - I have tethering enabled so the view is 20 pixels shorter than normal.

Answer (score 5):

The view controller lifecycle is described in [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html).

In short, when `-view` is called the first time, `-viewDidLoad` is called. Even if the very first thing a view controller does to a view is set the frame, it still needs to access the view.

```
UIViewController *controller = [MyViewController myViewController];

// -viewDidLoad has not been called (if +myViewController doesn't call -view.)

UIView *view = [controller view];

// -viewDidLoad has been called.

view.frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.bounds;
```

Even if you use `controller.view.frame` the same logical sequence happens. `-viewDidLoad` will always be a called with a freshly deserialized view that has not been embedded into the view hierarchy.

---

**Update**

It case it wasn't clear earlier, I was pointing out why the bounds of view are not set correctly in `-viewDidLoad`. It is only after `-viewDidLoad` does the view controller's view get added to the view hierarchy. This is when the final frame of the view is set.

If you must have the frame be the right dimensions, you can use IB to set the dimensions that you know you'll need or (if you don't use IB) set the frame in `-loadView`. This approach is flawed because it statically sets the size of the frame to a value that may be changed after `-viewDidLoad` is called (things like the in-call status bar).

---

**Update 2**

You need to split the adding subviews from positioning and sizing subviews.

If you are loading from a Storyboard or a Nib, then you are correct, additional views needed should be added in `-viewDidLoad`. If you're loading programmatically, then all subviews are added in `-loadView`.

The second task is positioning and sizing subviews. The preferred method is to use [UIView.autoresizingMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask), but for more precise layout, [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) view.bounds and adjust your custom subviews when view controller's view changes its size.

Comment: Even if I request [controller view] immediately after creating the controller, it makes no difference. First I create the controller. Second, I (for now) just assign the controller's view to a variable - just to reference it. Then I change the frame. For any demand-loaded cycles this works - for any triggered in the view didLoad of the mainVC, it does not.
If I have misunderstood, and you are referring to my mainVC in your example, then how am I meant to load some other view controllers at launch, and add their views?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear`-viewDidLoad` will always be called before the final bounds or frame is set. Always. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Where should I add subviews? In viewWillAppear? Seems like I would be doing a lot of unnecessary reprocessing.

Comment: The short answer is split add subviews from positioning and sizing subviews.

Comment: @Jeffery Thomas: I have a similar question here, I think your feedback would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882199/view-height-problems-continued